# Jquery mobile first time use tutorial

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

I'm wondering how to develop a first time use tutorial for my app with several pages just like the Zombies Run app that have 10 initial screens and you have to slide through all the screens, then you can start to use the app.

How i can accomplish that, should i use a panel or link several pages ?

I already tried searching the web, and i dont know if it is a kind of spashscreen or something.

It should be quite simple, but i coudn't find anything on web and on jquery mobile demos official website.

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage. At the beginning of your app, check for a variable ,say `first_time`

```
localStorage.getItem("first_time");

if(first_time=="")
{ // show tutorial
  localStorage.setItem("first_time","NO");
}
```

So next time when app runs it won't show the tutorial, cause next time `first_time` variable won't be null.

Now you can show tutorial in many ways. You can use a video or a slider

[slider links](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/03/10-jquery-mobile-responsive-slider-plugins.html)

At the begging this will be hidden. If it's the first time use it will be shown, otherwise won't.

Comment: localStorage is great. You can generally store up to 5MB.

Answer (score 0):

tks a lot for your instrucions.
Actually i used the slider links to build a sample app that can be tested on this [fiddle][1].

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ftfernandes/yrszc3z5/26/ using `<div class="swiper-container">`

Next step, i will improve it with the localstorage.

tks again